# php Version in Zend project differs from server version

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, zend-framework3

I'm developing with Zend 3* on a WAMP System.

Updating composer fails with an error message like this:

> composer require zendframework/zend-crypt
>
> - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
>
>   - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your PHP version (5.6.31) does not satisfy that requirement.
>   - Installation request for paragonie/random_compat (locked at v9.99.99) -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].

A sideremark: I already installed crypt and it worked, only because I got the browser message bcrypt couldn't be found, I tried to install again.

My composer.json looks like follows:

```
{
    "name" : "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description" : "Skeleton Application for Zend Framework zend-mvc applications",
    "type" : "project",
    "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords" : [
        "framework",
        "mvc",
        "zf"
    ],
    "homepage" : "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "prefer-stable" : true,
    "require" : {
        "php" : "^5.6 || ^7.0",
        "zendframework/zend-component-installer" : "^1.0 || ^0.7 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc" : "^3.1",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode" : "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-cache" : "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-db" : "^2.10",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-form" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-json" : "^3.0",
        "zendframework/zend-log" : "^2.9",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-console" : "^1.1.10",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-mvc-plugins" : "^1.0.1",
        "zendframework/zend-psr7bridge" : "^0.2.2",
        "zendframework/zend-session" : "^2.7.1",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager-di" : "^1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-paginator" : "^2.8",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager" : "^3.3",
        "zendframework/zend-validator" : "^2.10",
        "zendframework/zend-inputfilter" : "^2.8",
        "zendframework/zend-form" : "^2.12",
        "zendframework/zend-authentication" : "^2.6",
        "zendframework/zend-crypt" : "^3.3"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Application\\" : "module/Application/src/",
            "Stammdaten\\" : "module/Stammdaten/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "ApplicationTest\\" : "module/Application/test/"
        }
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "cs-check" : "phpcs",
        "cs-fix" : "phpcbf",
        "development-disable" : "zf-development-mode disable",
        "development-enable" : "zf-development-mode enable",
        "development-status" : "zf-development-mode status",
        "post-create-project-cmd" : "@development-enable",
        "serve" : "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php",
        "test" : "phpunit"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools" : "^1.1.0",
        "zendframework/zend-test" : "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

My localhost shows php Version: 
[image]

WAMP also shows this Version:

[image]

Only my commandbox confirmed the error above, **it really shows php 5.6.31.**

[image]

My first question is, why is that? Why doesn't use a new Project not automatically the server version?
And last, how can I change to the right version?

Comment: Please adjust the tagging: Neither any framework nor composer is responsible for changing some PHP version. Probably, you should check on your local computer why there are two versions of PHP installed on your computer

Comment: Remove `^5.6 ||` from line `"php" : "^5.6 || ^7.0",` in your composer.json file. The check it fails on goes on the highest value of the lowest option (so, 5.6.31 is the highest value of the lowest option (`^5.6`) of your required PHP version.) Also, to use "paragonie/halite", enable PHP's "sodium" module in your `php.ini` file like so: add `extension=sodium` on its own line to the bottom of that file. Requires minimum PHP `^7.2` (so might want to adjust that in your composer.json as well).

Answer (score -2):

Live can be quite easy.

Because it ran before with bcrypt, I searched around and a composer update and server reset brought the success.

Comment: Can you explain that further? You've asked about differing PHP versions. How does updating composer solve this?

Comment: Suddebnly I got an error about the wrong php version. A week before everything worked fine, so in fact it couldn't have to do smth with the php version. I searched a bit the web and somebody had the same, there was propably a bug in some composer version. This is what I think, because in the composer.json you have always each version and actually who is working with version 5.x? So try and error, in the end the error message was confusing.